# Visual Studio Code: how to add custom phrase to trigger SQL syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a php file, if I start a SQL string like:

`$sql = "SELECT ";`

Visual Studio will highlight the syntax. How do I add phrases like "DECLARE" and "SET NOCOUNT ON" to that functionality? I would like the editor to highlight the query when the string starts with:

`$sql = "DECLARE test int;";`